# Error while trying to generate chart as afile for PDF usage

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apexcharts

I am getting an error while trying to generate chart as afile for PDF usage.

```
const donutOptions: ApexOptions = {
    labels: names,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'donut',
      id: 'donutChart',
      width: '350px',
      height: 160,
      events: {
        dataPointSelection: (chart, options, value) => {
          const selected = {
            percentage: value.w.config.series[value.selectedDataPoints[0]],
            name: value.w.config.labels[value.selectedDataPoints[0]],
          };
          setValue(selected as SelectedValuesType);
        },
        dataPointMouseEnter: (event, cc, value) => {
          const percentage = value.w.config.series[value.dataPointIndex] as number;
          const name = value.w.config.labels[value.dataPointIndex];
          setCurrentHover({ percentage, name });
        },
        dataPointMouseLeave: () => {
          setCurrentHover({} as { percentage: number; name: string });
        },
      },
    },
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 500,
        options: {
          chart: {
            width: '300px',
            height: 160,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        expandOnClick: false,
        donut: {
          size: '70%',
        },
      },
    },
    colors: colors as string[],
    states: {
      active: {
        allowMultipleDataPointsSelection: true,
        filter: {
          type: 'darken',
          value: 0.35,
        },
      },
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false,
      theme: 'dark',
      style: {
        fontSize: '12px',
        fontFamily: 'Poppins, sans-serif',
      },
      y: {
        formatter: (value) => `<span class="text-black">${value.toFixed(1)}%</span`,
      },
    },
    legend: {
      show: false,
    },
  };
```

This is my getURI function which gets base64 of chart:

```
  const getURI = async () => {
    await ApexCharts.exec('donutChart', 'render', []);
    ApexCharts.exec('donutChart', 'dataURI', []).then((res: any) => console.log(res));
  };
```

and also tried to put config in exec as a third argument:

```
 const getURI = async () => {
    await ApexCharts.exec('donutChart', 'render', donutOptions);
    ApexCharts.exec('donutChart', 'dataURI', donutOptions).then((res: any) => console.log(res));
  };
```

I have tried to put width and height as a string and as a number, but every time I'm getting same error.

This is an error I'm getting:

[image: This is an error I'm getting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need it for PDF usage you can hard code height and width. And it should work.

eg.

```
const getURI = async () => {
    await ApexCharts.exec('donutChart', 'render', {width: 300, height: 160});
    ApexCharts.exec('donutChart', 'dataURI', {width: 300, height: 160}).then((res: any) => console.log(res));
  };
```

Comment: It looks it's the only way for now